# Inceptionv3 Transfer Learning on Torch

Tags: conv-neural-network, torch

Is there code for an implementation of transfer learning on torch using Incpetionv3 by training it on a  custom dataset ? I have obtained the model from https://github.com/Moodstocks/inception-v3.torch